# Use a string key name with React PropTypes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, react-proptypes

I'm in a position where I need to use strings as the keys for an object that I am passing as props to a few of my React components. Is there a way to make this work with React PropTypes and pass eslint?

Here is some example code:

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  'string-key-name': PropTypes.shape({
    foo: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    bar: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  }).isRequired,
};
```

In the above code, `string-key-name` is causing the issue. I need to use `-` in the key name of this object. Is this possible?

***EDIT***

I tried putting square brackets around the string key like `['string-key-name']` and it did not work.

***EDIT 2***

The eslint error I am getting is a missing props validation error. Oddly, `'string-key-name'` is not missing but `foo` and `bar` are.

```
'.foo' is missing in props validation       react/prop-types
'.bar' is missing in props validation       react/prop-types
```

Comment: what's the error/warning your linter shows?

Comment: @gforce301 It says the props are missing in props validation

Comment: are you passing the prop in to your component? if not, take out the `.isRequired`

Comment: @imjared Yes, I am passing them into my component and yes, they are required

Comment: If you really need to use a string, just disable eslint for that line, `// eslint-disable-line`

Comment: Could you post the component where from you are trying to pass this prop?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: This is a totally irrelevant answer because of lack of information.

If you want to use square brackets, you should put a variable instead of a string literal.

```
const keyName = 'string-key-name';
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  [keyName]: PropTypes.shape({
    foo: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    bar: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  }).isRequired,
};
```

However, I think you can just disable eslint in this case because you want to use `-` anyway.

```
'string-key-name': PropTypes.shape({ // eslint-disable-line
```

or

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
'string-key-name': PropTypes.shape({
```

will do the trick.

Comment: How didn't it work? Did you get a runtime error or get an eslint error? Can you post the error?

Comment: I just added another edit to the question with the error message

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.

In `MyComponent` I was destructuring the props out like so:

```
render() {
  const { foo, bar } = this.props['string-key-name'];
  return (
    <div>
      {bar}
    </div>
  );
```

When I modified my code like below, the props validation issue disappeared.

```
render() {
  const props = this.props;
  return (
    <div>
      {props['string-key-name'].bar}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: `this.props['string-key-name'].bar` and `this.props.bar` are different things. Does it work correctly?

Comment: @ShuheiKagawa My mistake, the answer has been updated to be correct